# Unterschied zwischen "sich aufhalten" und "Zeit verbringen"

Tags: meaning, difference

Könnte jemand mich in die richtige Richtung weisen bei einem Problem das ich momentan habe? Ich wollte wissen, ob "sich aufhalten" und "Zeit verbringen" in vielen Fällen gleichbedeutend sind.

Beispiele:

1. Ich verbringe viel Zeit im Freien.
   Ich halte mich oft im Freien auf.
2. Er verbringt zu viel Zeit bei der Arbeit.
   Er hält sich bei der Arbeit auf.
3. Ich werde keine Zeit mehr mit diesem Problem verbringen.
   Ich halte mich nicht länger mit diesem Problem auf.

Gibt es Unterschiede in den obigen Sätzen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im ersten Beispiel finde ich die Sätze fast gleichbedeutend. Eventuell (und dies ist sehr subtil und womöglich sehr individuell), erscheint mir, *Ich verbringe viel Zeit im Freien.* einen Tick "aktiver" als der zweite Satz, da "aufhalten" eher passiv ist. Jedenfalls stelle ich mir bei "Zeit verbringen" vor, dass du irgendeine Tätigkeit ausführst, während "aufhalten" erstmal nur bedeutet, dass du draußen bist.

*Er verbringt zu viel Zeit bei der Arbeit.* klingt natürlich. *Er hält sich bei der Arbeit auf.* klingt für mich unnatürlich und unter Umständen missverständlich: Befindet er sich irgendwo bei der Arbeitsstelle (ohne notwendigerweise zu arbeiten). Oder ist etwa gemeint, dass er mit der Arbeit nicht vorankommt, da er sich selbst irgendwie davon abhält? In jedem Fall fehlt das "zu viel" vom ersten Satz im zweiten Satz.

*Zeit mit einem Problem verbringen* betont, die **Zeit**, die du mit dem Problem verbracht hast. Der zweite Satz, mit "aufhalten" klingt für mich eher so, dass das Problem eine **Hürde** darstellt, da du es nicht lösen kannst. Wobei ich mir beim letzten Teil nicht sicher bin, da es im Prinzip "sich mit etwas aufhalten" mit "von etwas aufgehalten werden" gleichsetzt.

---

Dieser Teil der Antwort entstand bevor die Frage editiert wurde.

> *Ich werde keine Zeit mehr bei diesem Problem verbringen. Ich halte mich nicht länger bei diesem Problem auf.* würde ich so nur sagen,
>   wenn es mehrere Probleme gibt, und ich von diesem Problem auf ein
>   anderes Problem wechsle. Die Betonung läge dann auf "diesem". Wenn ich
>   diese Sätze lese, entsteht bei mir ein Bild von einer Art "Karte", wo
>   ich von einem Problem zum nächsten gehe.
>
> Für mich (und dies könnte wieder sehr individuell sein) wären diese
>   beiden Sätze natürlicher wenn das Wort *bei* durch *mit* ersetzt
>   würde.

Comment: Vielen Dank für die Erklärung! Deine Antwort hat mir dabei geholfen, mein Verständis dieses Wörtes zu vertiefen. Wenn ich darf, möchte ich dir noch eine Frage stellen. Ich glaube, dass ich die Verwendung des Wortes im Zusammenhang der letzten zwei Sätze jetzt gut verstehe, aber bei dem ersten besteht noch Verwirrung für mich. Zum Beispiel, wenn man sich gerne draußen aufhält, bedeutet dass, das er sich zufällig draußen befindet, und dann entscheidet, draußen zu bleiben? Order macht er das regalmäßig zum Beispiel für sportliche Aktivitäten oder es gefällt ihm, draußen Zeit zu verbringen?

Comment: @Mark: Hinsichtlich gefallen/nichtgefallen sind beide Sätze neutral, d.h. sie treffen keine Aussage. Wie gesagt, der Unterschied ist minimal und es ist gut möglich, dass jemand anderes hier gar keinen Unterschied sieht.